# aria2c had to connect to the other side using an unknown TLS protocol, why?

Tags: networking, ssl, aria2, gnutls

When I run

```
aria2c https://www.example.com
```

I get

```
02/24 15:33:38 [WARN] aria2c had to connect to the other side using an unknown TLS protocol. The integrity and confidentiality of the connection might be compromised.
```

Why is this? Note that this isn't specific to `www.example.com`; it happens on many if not all hosts.

For reference, here's the (redacted) log:

```
[INFO] [Context.cc:182] aria2 1.34.0
[INFO] [Context.cc:183] gcc 8.2.1 20181127
  built by  x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  on        Feb  8 2019 09:32:06
[INFO] [Context.cc:185] zlib/1.2.11 libxml2/2.9.9 sqlite3/3.26.0 GnuTLS/3.6.6 nettle GMP/6.1.2 c-ares/1.15.0 libssh2/1.8.0
[INFO] [Context.cc:186] Logging started.
[DEBUG] [Context.cc:216] Not setting rlimit NO_FILE: 1024 >= 1024
[NOTICE] [Context.cc:311] Downloading 1 item(s)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: common.c[_gnutls_x509_get_raw_field2]:1570
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: x509.c[gnutls_x509_crt_get_subject_unique_id]:3902
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: x509.c[gnutls_x509_crt_get_issuer_unique_id]:3952
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: dn.c[_gnutls_x509_compare_raw_dn]:990
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: dn.c[_gnutls_x509_compare_raw_dn]:990
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: dn.c[_gnutls_x509_compare_raw_dn]:990
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: dn.c[_gnutls_x509_compare_raw_dn]:990
[INFO] [LibgnutlsTLSContext.cc:158] 135 certificate(s) were imported.
[DEBUG] [RequestGroupMan.cc:591] 1 RequestGroup(s) added.
[DEBUG] [AbstractCommand.cc:184] CUID#7 - socket: read:0, write:0, hup:0, err:0
[DEBUG] [FeedbackURISelector.cc:162] Selected from normCands
[DEBUG] [FeedbackURISelector.cc:84] FeedbackURISelector selected https://www.example.com
[DEBUG] [AbstractCommand.cc:184] CUID#7 - socket: read:0, write:0, hup:0, err:0
[INFO] [AsyncNameResolverMan.cc:83] CUID#7 - Resolving hostname www.example.com
[DEBUG] [EpollEventPoll.cc:260] Failed to delete socket event:Bad file descriptor
[DEBUG] [AbstractCommand.cc:184] CUID#7 - socket: read:0, write:0, hup:0, err:0
[INFO] [AbstractCommand.cc:817] CUID#7 - Name resolution complete: www.example.com -> 93.184.216.34
[INFO] [HttpInitiateConnectionCommand.cc:123] CUID#7 - Connecting to 93.184.216.34:443
[DEBUG] [AbstractCommand.cc:184] CUID#7 - socket: read:0, write:0, hup:0, err:0
[DEBUG] [AbstractCommand.cc:184] CUID#7 - socket: read:0, write:1, hup:0, err:0
[DEBUG] [AbstractCommand.cc:184] CUID#7 - socket: read:0, write:1, hup:0, err:0
[DEBUG] [SocketCore.cc:926] Creating TLS session
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Allocating epoch #0
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> added 6 protocols, 29 ciphersuites, 17 sig algos and 9 groups into priority list
[DEBUG] [SocketCore.cc:946] TLS Handshaking
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Allocating epoch #1
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> HSK[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Adv. version: 3.3
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite 13.02 (GNUTLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite 13.03 (GNUTLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite 13.01 (GNUTLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite 13.04 (GNUTLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite c0.2c (GNUTLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite cc.a9 (GNUTLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_CHACHA20_POLY1305)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite c0.0a (GNUTLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite c0.ad (GNUTLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_AES_256_CCM)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite c0.2b (GNUTLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite c0.09 (GNUTLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite c0.ac (GNUTLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_AES_128_CCM)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite c0.30 (GNUTLS_ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite cc.a8 (GNUTLS_ECDHE_RSA_CHACHA20_POLY1305)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite c0.14 (GNUTLS_ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite c0.2f (GNUTLS_ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite c0.13 (GNUTLS_ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite 00.9d (GNUTLS_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite 00.35 (GNUTLS_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite c0.9d (GNUTLS_RSA_AES_256_CCM)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite 00.9c (GNUTLS_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite 00.2f (GNUTLS_RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite c0.9c (GNUTLS_RSA_AES_128_CCM)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite 00.9f (GNUTLS_DHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite cc.aa (GNUTLS_DHE_RSA_CHACHA20_POLY1305)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite 00.39 (GNUTLS_DHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite c0.9f (GNUTLS_DHE_RSA_AES_256_CCM)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite 00.9e (GNUTLS_DHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite 00.33 (GNUTLS_DHE_RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Keeping ciphersuite c0.9e (GNUTLS_DHE_RSA_AES_128_CCM)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing extension (Maximum Record Size/1) for 'client hello'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing extension (OCSP Status Request/5) for 'client hello'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sending extension OCSP Status Request/5 (5 bytes)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing extension (Client Certificate Type/19) for 'client hello'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing extension (Server Certificate Type/20) for 'client hello'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing extension (Supported Groups/10) for 'client hello'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sent group SECP256R1 (0x17)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sent group SECP384R1 (0x18)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sent group SECP521R1 (0x19)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sent group X25519 (0x1d)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sent group FFDHE2048 (0x100)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sent group FFDHE3072 (0x101)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sent group FFDHE4096 (0x102)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sent group FFDHE6144 (0x103)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sent group FFDHE8192 (0x104)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sending extension Supported Groups/10 (20 bytes)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing extension (Supported EC Point Formats/11) for 'client hello'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sending extension Supported EC Point Formats/11 (2 bytes)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing extension (SRP/12) for 'client hello'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing extension (Signature Algorithms/13) for 'client hello'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: sent signature algo (4.1) RSA-SHA256
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: sent signature algo (8.9) RSA-PSS-SHA256
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: sent signature algo (8.4) RSA-PSS-RSAE-SHA256
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: sent signature algo (4.3) ECDSA-SHA256
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: sent signature algo (8.7) EdDSA-Ed25519
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: sent signature algo (5.1) RSA-SHA384
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: sent signature algo (8.10) RSA-PSS-SHA384
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: sent signature algo (8.5) RSA-PSS-RSAE-SHA384
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: sent signature algo (5.3) ECDSA-SHA384
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: sent signature algo (6.1) RSA-SHA512
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: sent signature algo (8.11) RSA-PSS-SHA512
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: sent signature algo (8.6) RSA-PSS-RSAE-SHA512
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: sent signature algo (6.3) ECDSA-SHA512
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: sent signature algo (2.1) RSA-SHA1
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sending extension Signature Algorithms/13 (30 bytes)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing extension (SRTP/14) for 'client hello'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing extension (Heartbeat/15) for 'client hello'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing extension (ALPN/16) for 'client hello'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing extension (Encrypt-then-MAC/22) for 'client hello'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sending extension Encrypt-then-MAC/22 (0 bytes)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing extension (Extended Master Secret/23) for 'client hello'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sending extension Extended Master Secret/23 (0 bytes)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing extension (Session Ticket/35) for 'client hello'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sending extension Session Ticket/35 (0 bytes)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing extension (Key Share/51) for 'client hello'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: sending key share for SECP256R1
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: sending key share for X25519
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sending extension Key Share/51 (107 bytes)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing extension (Supported Versions/43) for 'client hello'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Advertizing version 3.4
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Advertizing version 3.3
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Advertizing version 3.2
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> Advertizing version 3.1
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sending extension Supported Versions/43 (9 bytes)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing extension (Post Handshake Auth/49) for 'client hello'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing extension (Safe Renegotiation/65281) for 'client hello'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sending extension Safe Renegotiation/65281 (1 bytes)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing extension (Server Name Indication/0) for 'client hello'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> HSK[0x7fffd8c6c880]: sent server name: 'www.example.com'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sending extension Server Name Indication/0 (20 bytes)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing extension (Cookie/44) for 'client hello'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing extension (Early Data/42) for 'client hello'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing extension (PSK Key Exchange Modes/45) for 'client hello'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sending extension PSK Key Exchange Modes/45 (3 bytes)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing extension (Record Size Limit/28) for 'client hello'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sending extension Record Size Limit/28 (2 bytes)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing extension (ClientHello Padding/21) for 'client hello'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing extension (Pre Shared Key/41) for 'client hello'
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> HSK[0x7fffd8c6c880]: CLIENT HELLO was queued [354 bytes]
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing Packet Handshake(22) with length: 354 and min pad: 0
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sent Packet[1] Handshake(22) in epoch 0 and length: 359
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: buffers.c[get_last_packet]:1171
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: buffers.c[_gnutls_io_read_buffered]:589
[DEBUG] [AbstractCommand.cc:184] CUID#7 - socket: read:1, write:0, hup:0, err:0
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: buffers.c[get_last_packet]:1171
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: SSL 3.3 Handshake packet received. Epoch 0, length: 123
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Expected Packet Handshake(22)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Received Packet Handshake(22) with length: 123
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Decrypted Packet[0] Handshake(22) with length: 123
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> HSK[0x7fffd8c6c880]: SERVER HELLO (2) was received. Length 119[119], frag offset 0, frag length: 119, sequence: 0
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: buffers.c[get_last_packet]:1162
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: buffers.c[_gnutls_handshake_io_recv_int]:1413
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> HSK[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Server's version: 3.3
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Parsing extension 'Supported Versions/43' (2 bytes)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Negotiated version: 3.4
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> HSK[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Selected cipher suite: GNUTLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Parsing extension 'Key Share/51' (69 bytes)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> HSK[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Selected group SECP256R1 (2)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <2> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: client generated SECP256R1 shared key
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing Packet ChangeCipherSpec(20) with length: 1 and min pad: 0
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sent Packet[2] ChangeCipherSpec(20) in epoch 0 and length: 6
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sent ChangeCipherSpec
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Initializing epoch #1
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Epoch #1 ready
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> HSK[0x7fffd8c6c880]: TLS 1.3 re-key with cipher suite: GNUTLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: buffers.c[get_last_packet]:1171
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: SSL 3.3 ChangeCipherSpec packet received. Epoch 1, length: 1
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Expected Packet Handshake(22)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Received Packet ChangeCipherSpec(20) with length: 1
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: SSL 3.3 Application Data packet received. Epoch 1, length: 27
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Expected Packet Handshake(22)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Received Packet Application Data(23) with length: 27
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Decrypted Packet[0] Handshake(22) with length: 10
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> HSK[0x7fffd8c6c880]: ENCRYPTED EXTENSIONS (8) was received. Length 6[6], frag offset 0, frag length: 6, sequence: 0
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> HSK[0x7fffd8c6c880]: parsing encrypted extensions
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> EXT[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Parsing extension 'Server Name Indication/0' (0 bytes)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: buffers.c[get_last_packet]:1171
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: SSL 3.3 Application Data packet received. Epoch 1, length: 4502
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Expected Packet Handshake(22)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Received Packet Application Data(23) with length: 4502
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Decrypted Packet[1] Handshake(22) with length: 4485
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> HSK[0x7fffd8c6c880]: CERTIFICATE (11) was received. Length 4481[4481], frag offset 0, frag length: 4481, sequence: 0
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: buffers.c[get_last_packet]:1162
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: buffers.c[_gnutls_handshake_io_recv_int]:1413
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> HSK[0x7fffd8c6c880]: parsing certificate message
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> Found OCSP response on cert 0
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: buffers.c[get_last_packet]:1171
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: SSL 3.3 Application Data packet received. Epoch 1, length: 281
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Expected Packet Handshake(22)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Received Packet Application Data(23) with length: 281
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Decrypted Packet[2] Handshake(22) with length: 264
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> HSK[0x7fffd8c6c880]: CERTIFICATE VERIFY (15) was received. Length 260[260], frag offset 0, frag length: 260, sequence: 0
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> HSK[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Parsing certificate verify
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> HSK[0x7fffd8c6c880]: verifying TLS 1.3 handshake data using RSA-PSS-RSAE-SHA256
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: buffers.c[get_last_packet]:1171
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: SSL 3.3 Application Data packet received. Epoch 1, length: 69
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Expected Packet Handshake(22)
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Received Packet Application Data(23) with length: 69
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Decrypted Packet[3] Handshake(22) with length: 52
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> HSK[0x7fffd8c6c880]: FINISHED (20) was received. Length 48[48], frag offset 0, frag length: 48, sequence: 0
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> HSK[0x7fffd8c6c880]: parsing finished
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> HSK[0x7fffd8c6c880]: sending finished
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> HSK[0x7fffd8c6c880]: FINISHED was queued [52 bytes]
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Preparing Packet Handshake(22) with length: 52 and min pad: 0
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Sent Packet[1] Handshake(22) in epoch 1 and length: 74
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: constate.c[_gnutls_epoch_get]:901
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Allocating epoch #2
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Initializing epoch #2
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Epoch #2 ready
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <4> HSK[0x7fffd8c6c880]: TLS 1.3 re-key with cipher suite: GNUTLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Start of epoch cleanup
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Epoch #0 freed
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: Epoch #1 freed
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <5> REC[0x7fffd8c6c880]: End of epoch cleanup
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: common.c[_gnutls_x509_get_raw_field2]:1570
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: ocsp.c[find_signercert]:1996
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: common.c[_gnutls_x509_der_encode]:876
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: ocsp.c[find_signercert]:2091
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: common.c[_gnutls_x509_get_raw_field2]:1570
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: ocsp.c[gnutls_ocsp_resp_verify]:2352
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: common.c[_gnutls_x509_get_raw_field2]:1570
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: ocsp.c[find_signercert]:1996
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: common.c[_gnutls_x509_der_encode]:876
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: ocsp.c[find_signercert]:2091
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: mpi.c[wrap_nettle_mpi_print]:60
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: mpi.c[wrap_nettle_mpi_print]:60
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ocsp signer: subject `CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US', issuer `CN=DigiCert Global Root CA,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US', serial 0x01fda3eb6eca75c888438b724bcfbc91, RSA key 2048 bits, signed using RSA-SHA256, activated `2013-03-08 12:00:00 UTC', expires `2023-03-08 12:00:00 UTC', pin-sha256="5kJvNEMw0KjrCAu7eXY5HZdvyCS13BbA0VJG1RSP91w="
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: ocsp.c[gnutls_ocsp_resp_get_single]:1649
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: ocsp-api.c[gnutls_ocsp_status_request_get2]:99
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: ocsp-api.c[gnutls_ocsp_status_request_get2]:99
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: name_constraints.c[gnutls_x509_crt_get_name_constraints]:470
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: name_constraints.c[gnutls_x509_crt_get_name_constraints]:470
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: x509_ext.c[gnutls_subject_alt_names_get]:110
[DEBUG] [Platform.cc:86] GnuTLS: <3> ASSERT: x509.c[get_alt_name]:1815
[WARN] [SocketCore.cc:979] aria2c had to connect to the other side using an unknown TLS protocol. The integrity and confidentiality of the connection might be compromised.
Peer: www.example.com (93.184.216.34:443)

02/24 15:38:26 [WARN] aria2c had to connect to the other side using an unknown TLS protocol. The integrity and confidentiality of the connection might be compromised.
...
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your log indicates `aria2c` is using the GnuTLS library, which is choosing TLS 1.3, as both the GnuTLS library and the server supports it.

But according to [this patch](https://github.com/aria2/aria2/commit/52da4e40ea22d1db13c1eadeac5baed4e8fd5dd8), `aria2c` did not know about the existence of TLS 1.3 until April 7 of 2019. And since your question is dated February 24, your log snippet is clearly older than that patch.

So, this is just GnuTLS library reporting that it's using TLS 1.3 and `aria2c` not understanding what "TLS 1.3" is.

Once you update `aria2c` to a version that includes that patch, `aria2c` will understand what GnuTLS is saying when it reports a connection using TLS 1.3, and will be able to report that correctly to the user, so the problem will go away.

Unfortunately, at the time of this writing, the newest release is 1.34.0, which was released in May 2018 and so it's too old to include the TLS 1.3 patch. Until a new release version of `aria2c` is created, the only ways to get a version of `aria2c` that supports TLS 1.3 without those annoying messages would be to [get the latest source code from GitHub](https://github.com/aria2/aria2) and compile it yourself, or to find someone distributing a modified version of `aria2c` 1.34.0 with this patch backported in.

---

`aria2c` version 1.35.0 was released in October 6, 2019, and that release finally includes TLS 1.3 support.

Comment: Wow, May 2018! And here I thought Arch kept up with package releases. :\ Thanks!

Comment: Well, `aria2c` 1.34.0 **is** the latest package release so far, so one cannot blame Arch here. It's just that the author of `aria2c` hasn't made a new *release* yet that would include the necessary bits for true TLS 1.3 support. It looks like `aria2c` has reached the point of transition from innovative development to maintenance mode, and the latter can be uninteresting to a developer.

Comment: Ah I see. It's weird this error hasn't bothered anyone for so long. I wonder if most people are just ignoring it?